# Wrong number or types of arguments when calling a procedure in WCF service

Tags: oracle, web-services, wcf, visual-studio-2013

I'm sort of having a hard time with this one. Well ok, I have two different solutions (solution1 has a WebApplication Project; solution2 has a Website Project). Inside the two solutions, there's a WCF service structure. I have the exact same code in both services (in their respective solutions). My code compiles just fine. From the service I do a simple call to a procedure that returns a cursor. When I execute the service from the WebApplication it works just fine; when I do the same from the Website I get error: "wrong number or types of arguments". They both call the same procedure, in the same DB. And I triple check my code, and is the same in both services. Any ideas or suggestions? My code is as follows in both solutions:
Service.cs

```
public List<A1001310> SearchClient_A1001310()
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataTable = DataManager.SearchClient();

        List<A1001310> list = new List<A1001310>();
        list = (from DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows
                select new A1001310()
                {
                    Id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["CLIENT_ID"]),
                    //ClientName = dr["NOM_CLIENTE"].ToString()
                }).ToList();
        return list;
    }
```

DataManager.cs

```
public static DataTable SearchClient()
    {
        try
        {
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(packetName + ".select_A1001310"))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                SqlManager sqlManager = new SqlManager();                    
                return sqlManager.GetDataTable(cmd);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //TODO; Handle exception
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The call to DataTable is:

```
public DataTable GetDataTable(OleDbCommand cmd)
    {
        using (DataSet ds = GetDataSet(cmd))
        {
            return ((ds != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0) ? ds.Tables[0] : null);
        }
    }

public DataSet GetDataSet(OleDbCommand cmd)
    {
        using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
        {
            this.ConvertToNullBlankParameters(cmd);

            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(cmd.Connection == null ? _dbConnection : cmd.Connection.ConnectionString))
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandTimeout = _connTimeout;

                conn.Open();
                //cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
                    da.Fill(ds);
            }
            return ds;
        }
    }
```

The procedure is as follow:

```
    PROCEDURE select_A1001310(io_cursor OUT lcursor_data)
  AS
  BEGIN
    OPEN io_cursor FOR
    --
      SELECT client_id
        FROM a1001310
       WHERE status = 'A'
    --
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      IF io_cursor%ISOPEN THEN
        CLOSE io_cursor;
      END IF;
    --REVIRE: EXCEPTION HANDLER
  END select_A1001310;
```

Comment: Where does the error occur? Post the *full* exception, including the call stack. You can get it by calling `Exception.ToString()`

Comment: What is `packagename`? Unless it's exactly the same in all cases, you are aclling a different stored procedure each time. Different procedures may have a different number of arguments

Comment: `SqlManager` isn't an ADO.NET class either. What does `GetDataTable` do? Does it set any parameters?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your fast response. (1) This is the exception: Message "ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SELECT_A1001310'\nORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPL/SQL: Statement ignored" string   (2) The package name is the same in both service call. (3) GetDataTable returns a DataTable; on the package I return a cursor.

Comment: Post the *code*, don't describe it. That's *not* the exception either, that's just the message. The full exception contains the call stack, which shows *where* the exception occured. I'd guess somewhere inside GetDataTable. Oracle obviously believes that it needs parameters - how many? Where are they set? The code you posted doesn't contain anything about parameters. Where do you set them?

Comment: I updated my post...

Comment: Your stored procedure expects a cursor output parameter. That's exactly what the error complained about. Why do you use a stored procedure *at all* for a simple SELECT query? Why not use an ORM like EF or a microORM like Dapper?

Answer (score 0):

So if it helps anyone, I resolved my issue by specifying the OUT parameter declared in the procedure. This resulted in me changing from Oledb to OracleClient as follow:

```
public static DataTable SearchClient()
    {
        string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection_Oracle"].ToString();
        string procedure = packetName + ".p_search_client";

        OracleParameter[] parameters = new OracleParameter[1];
        parameters[0] = new OracleParameter("io_cursor", OracleType.Cursor, 4000, ParameterDirection.Output, true, 0, 0, "", DataRowVersion.Current, String.Empty);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = DataManager_Oracle.GetDataTable_(connection, procedure, parameters);
        return dt;
    }
```

It seems that on the Website environment it didn't like leaving out the OUT parameter; whereas on the WebApplication I did not specify it, and it worked just fine... If some one know the why , PLEASE let me know :)

Comment: It didn't work just fine, your code hid the error as specified by `catch(Excpection exc){}`. There was an error but you didn't notice. You *have* to specify all parameters